# Ran sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock now the keyboard or the mouse does not work on login screen

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mouse

Title pretty much says it all. I was refered with another problem i had to a answer which said i should do that command. Now the drivers seems to be uninstalled. I can't move the mouse or the keyboard when i come to the login screen. It works in GRUB though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see removing the lock file effecting your keyboard, however what happened to produce the orphaned lock file could be related. try doing

```
apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I have no idea how it happend either.. Basiclly a window popped up and said Your graphics driver has stopped working so graphics are working on minimal resource or whatever it said then all the drivers stopped working and when i restarted the computer it didn't got back to normal. 
apt-get -f install does not work and it doesn't even work in recovery mode.